# confusion with Java wildcards

Tags: java

Please explain to me why I have one example that compiles and the other one doesn't compile

This is example that compiles

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass1 <T> {
    public ArrayList<MyClass1<?>> lst;

    public MyClass1()
    {
        lst = new ArrayList<MyClass1<?>>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        M(new MyClass1<Double>());
    }

    public static <T1> void M(MyClass1<T1> t1)
    {
        var d0 =  new MyClass1<Double>();
        d0.lst.add(t1);
    }
}
```

But that doesn't compiles

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass1 <T> {
    public ArrayList<?> lst;

    public MyClass1()
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        M(Double.valueOf(1.1));
    }

    public static <T1> void M(T1 t1)
    {
        var d0 =  new MyClass1<Double>();
        d0.lst.add(t1); // error — java: incompatible types: T1 cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?
    }
}
```

Why in the first case I have wildcard, and everything is OK, but in the second case I have wildcard and it doesn't compile

Comment: `MyClass1<Double>` is compatible with `MyClass1<?>` because at runtime they're the same thing, thanks to type erasure.
 
`Double` is not compatible with `?` because `?` represents something specific, but what it represents could be anything. It could be String, or an ArrayList, or an ExecutorService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second snippet can not be compiled because the generics in Java are about type safety(type guarantee). Thus, if we are declearing  `List<Integer>` the compiler is convinced, that the list will contain only integers. But when we have `List<?>` (read this like list of some type), compiler cant predict what will the list contain. Today we are adding Integers, tomorrow somebody else will add a ServerSocket. In runtime if we will try to get a value from such a list, we will get a ClassCastException. That is why this code cant even be compiled - to prevent such situations. Read about [type erasure and bridge methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).
In your concrete case, i guess, you would like to have something like this:

```java
public class MyClass<T> {
    public ArrayList<T> lst;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var obj = new MyClass<Double>();
        obj.foo(1.1);
    }

    public void foo(T s) {
        lst.add(s);
    }
}
```

The question mark also can be useful:

```java
static void m(List<? extends Shape> list) {
    for (Shape el : list) {
        // we are not quite interested what type is this list of.
    }
}
```

And the usage example:

```java
m(new ArrayList<Circle>());
m(new ArrayList<Shape>());
```